# Using a batch script to put files in a new folder named after them, how can I make it ignore everything between an underscore and a period?

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  @echo off
    for %%a in (*.*) do (
        md "%%~na" 2>nul
        move "%%a" "%%~na"
    )
```

If the files were named the same way, but with different extensions, it works fine.  But my files look like this:

MS394-19-1872.tif
MS394-19-1872_mods.xml
MS394-19-1872_dc.xml
MS371-01-05-012A.tif
MS371-01-05-012A_mods.xml
MS371-01-05-012A_dc.xml

I need them grouped in folders that are named using everything before the "." OR the "_" and everything thrown into folders matching that, so that each folder holds any file that has that first part in it:

MS371-01-05-012A contains 3 files
MS394-19-1872 contains 3 files

Alternatively, I can come up with another way to name the files, such as MS394-19-1872.mods.xml if that helps.

Comment: I'm assuming I leave the @echo off, correct?

Comment: I have moved my comment to the answer area, please try it, it was designed to work from the same directory as your own attempt. That is it will move all the files in the current directory, _which may also be that of your batch file depending upon how you run it_, to their respective new subdirectories.

Comment: I will re-run it when I'm back at my desk and let you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=_Delims=_" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D-S-L 2^>NUL')Do @If /I Not "%%~nxA"=="%~nx0" MD "%%~nA" 2>NUL&If Exist "%%A*" Move "%%A*" "%%~nA"
```

Please note that if your naming structure changes, this may no longer be effective. Also your batch file must not be named with an underscore.